# wildfly custom module: unable to use class inside deployed EAR

Tags: wildfly, classloader

I am creating a custom realm in wildfly that will be use by my application for login purposes. If I use the class inside a jar file of a global module, wildfly can find it. However, if I try pointing it to a class inside my EAR file, then wildfly cannot locate the class.

- Below config is working. VersaCustomRealm class is located inside VRCustomRealm.jar

standalone.xml

```
<custom-realm name="vr-login-realm" module="micropact.login" class-name="com.versa.login.VersaCustomRealm">
    <configuration>
        <property name="admin" value="welcome"/>
    </configuration>
</custom-realm>
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="micropact.login">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="VRCustomRealm.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.wildfly.security.elytron"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

- Below config does not work. What am I missing? What would be the correct module name for deployed EAR?

  ```
    <configuration>
        <property name="admin" value="welcome"/>
    </configuration>
  ```

Older version of wildfly still supports login-module where you can specify the custom code. In the below example, I use VersaCustomRealm which is a class inside my EAR file and not in the global module. How can accomplish this with custom realm?

```
<security-domain name="vr-domain" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="com.versasys.licenseEase.jbosssx.VersaCustomRealm" flag="required">
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can. The server needs anything listed in standalone from modules, before the deployment scanner starts

Comment: Thanks will for the response. Currently, I'm just trying to do everything in the custom module that I created and make it as a global module. Do you know how can this custom module use the libraries in EAR file as dependencies?

Comment: Your custom stuff needs to be a module. You can't depend from the module to the ear, only the other way round. So you custom code and any of it's dep as module. If any of your code inside the container also needs those classes, then the module can depend on the module

Comment: Thank you Will. I just created another module which contains the  jars that I need. Basically I have 2 modules now, one which contains my custom code and the other one is the jars that is use for dependency. All good now. Thank you so much for your help, appreciate it.